# HorizontalFlip inside PageViewController

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I have UIPageViewController which contains a couple of UIViews, in each of the view its possible to turn the UIView with an horizontal flip to a NavigationController containing only a view. I implemented this functionality but it seems that the flip only works the first time.

Here is how I flip the view in the first place:

```
UINavigationController *navController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BackViewController"];

//Pass some data to the back controller
[[[navController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] setDataObject:self.dataObject];

navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self.navigationController presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And here is how I turn it back:

```
PageRootController *pageRootController = [[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageRootController"] initWithData:self.mydata];

pageRootController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self.navigationController presentViewController:pageRootController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Like I said, this works good for the first time (I can flip it and then flip back), and does nothing once I tap it again. I'm new to iOS programming so if you need some more info I can paste it.

Comment: I don't really get what you want to do. Do you want a Navigation Controller inside a PageFlipViewController ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had a new navigation controller inside each of my views, instead of pushing and popping views from the current one.